# Docker containers eating up all the ram using windows 10

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I have 7 docker containers running, which in total take around 3gb of ram, according to docker stats

[image]

Im running docker with hyper-v in windows , im not using WSL / WSL-2 because the problem that im about to describe becomes even worse.

The problem is that hyper-v is demanding around 6.5-7gb ram instead of 3gb of ram
[image]

Why? If my containers barely take 3gb.  In result because of the high ram usage, im always hovering 15gb of total ram usage on windows 10, when I only have 16gb ram. If something weird happens , like changing branches in the container or whatever in a fast pace, the container eventually runs out of the assigned 8gb of memory and starts swapping with my ssd, which makes my pc crash.

With WSL the problem is even worse, since its straight up starts swapping even if i assign it a memory limit of 8gb in .wslconfig , hyper-v is at least somehwoe usable

Im running a node server, a react app, and a couple of proxys/databases. Im developing on it with VSC.
Any idea on how to fix this absurd amount of ram usage?

Comment: Have you tried to limit resources in the docker desktop settings?

Comment: @VarChar42 yes , the only thing that changes is that it will start swapping earlier , right now its limited to 8gb, if i limit it to 6gb it starts swapping at 6gb hence my pc crashes. I cant afford assgning more than 8gb

Comment: What about if you try and limit the resources on the containers itself? for instance, don't let every container have all 8gb of memory available, but limit every single one to .. lets say 1gb or 512mb so the container itself will see its memory limit, some processes are set up that they only start to clean up memory caches when they are close to all memory used they have available. That could help keep total memory used lower hence .. DD wont use so much memory?

Comment: @matic1123 that might be an option, ill give it a try